# page.evaluate doesn't work

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I want page.evaluate to run when my onLoadFinished is complete. But the following error is coming
MESSAGE: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: page

my code is:

```
page.property('onLoadFinished', function(status) {
            if(status==="success")
            {
                 try{
                    console.log('==== onLoadFinished()'+status);
                     page.evaluate(function () {
                    console.log("++++++++++++++++++"+document);
                    var Import = document.getElementById("Import");
                    if (Import){
                        console.log("+"+Import);
                        document.getElementById("start").value = "somedate";
                        document.getElementById("Import").click();
                    }else{console.log("Import not found");}
                })


        }catch(ex){

               var fullMessage = "\nJAVASCRIPT EXCEPTION";
               fullMessage += "\nMESSAGE: " + ex.toString();
               for (var p in ex) {
                   fullMessage += "\n" + p.toUpperCase() + ": " + ex[p];
               }
               console.log(fullMessage);
           }
        }
        })
```

Comment: what is 'page' ? is it an object defined by you? because it certainly isn't a window object

Answer (score 0):

page isn't a global variable as far as I know. You could use [windows.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) instead.

It fires when the entire page is loaded. So this is what you need!